# JPQL: why 'group by' does not work properly

Tags: hibernate, hql, jpql, entitymanager

Executing JPQL using hibernate 4.2.5:

```
select c from Chargeback as cc join cc.customer as c group by c order by max(cc.created)
```

Usecase: show customers with the latest chargbacks.

produces org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

1. When using
   `select c.id from Chargeback as cc join cc.customer as c group by c order by max(cc.created)` it will work.
2. When using `select c from Chargeback as cc join cc.customer as c group by c.id, c......all columns order by max(cc.created)`

Is it a bug? why JPQL does not include *? (from this usecase it is very necessary)

NO need - native sql of course to solve it. We assume JPQL is mature.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request for this: [HHH-1615](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1615).

However, keep in mind that grouping by all columns may not be the best option performance-wise.

Comment: Do you think better to have customerIds and then load it separately (new select) in case of millions records? Will it be wise?

Comment: Hopefully, you don't mean you load millions of records. In that case no solution will work. :) But if you group by all columns among millions of records, then yes, I would say avoiding that by using other approaches should yield better performance.