# Spring Data JPA: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: spring, oracle, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have two entities mapped with many to many:

```
    //Article entity
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="article_has_tags", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="article_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tag_id")})
    private List<Tag> tags;

    //Tag entity
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private List<Article> articles;
```

I try to write a query:

```
@Query("select t from Tag t join t.articles a group by t order by count(t) DESC")
List<Tag> getMostPopular(Pageable page);
```

But it fails with `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

full stacktrace here

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300)
org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy832.getResultList(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:110)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:74)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:97)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:88)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:395)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:373)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:486)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy814.getMostPopular(Unknown Source)
com.jahra.service.impl.TagServiceImpl.getPopularTags(TagServiceImpl.java:34)
com.jahra.controller.UserDashboardController.dashBoard(UserDashboardController.java:41)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

Where is my mistake?
P.S I want to fetch top tags with the largest number of articles.

Comment: Your query refers to `t` in many different ways, with different supposed meanings; can you please explain what `t` should be? Could you even post the structure of your tables?

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible to post structures. Imagine, that I have articles with ids [1,2,3] and tag with ids [1,2,3,4,5,6]. JoinTable has records like [1-1, 1-5, 2-1, 2-2, 2-5, 3-5]. Result list of top 2 tags should be tags with ids [1,5]. @Aleksej

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058953/jpql-why-group-by-does-not-work-properly) might be useful.